# How would I map a list of items to the arguments of another function?

Tags: kotlin, mapping

I am trying to figure out the best way to map my sorted map to the arguments of another function. This is an example of what I have.

```
data class ValueDescription (val length: Int, val count: Int)
// Now I am trying to map to a variable that looks like this
// This variable cannot be changed, I have to return this variable in this format
// The output will be a list of ValueDescriptions with a length and count for each entry of the map I have
// I will add the results of myValues to a mutable list later
val myValues = ValueDescription(_length here__, __count here__)
```

I have a sorted map that I want to map to my values

```
// The map will look like this
// Where both Ints hold the lengths and counts
// For example I would have the length of 7 to count of 8

val out = Map<Int, Int>
```

How can I take the values in my sorted map and place them into the variable myValues?

I tried to map by looping through my map with the forEach method and doing something like

```
out.map{it.key to myValues.ValueDescription.length}
```

but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `myValues` cannot be a single `ValueDescription` and at the same time represent all elements of the map. Do you mean you want a list of those? Could you please clarify?

Comment: Yes, I should have clarified that I want to have a list of ValueDescriptions for each entry of the map.

Comment: Then my answer should be what you're looking for. I don't understand why you're saying `This variable cannot be changed, I have to return this variable in this format`. If you have constraints like this, then probably we're missing the big picture. Please add more context. You probably shouldn't add things to a mutable list if you can just transform directly like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understood the question. If I got it correctly, your input is the `Map<Int, Int>` and you want to transform it to a `List<ValueDescription>`.

You can definitely use the `map` function for this:

```kotlin
val inputMap: Map<Int, Int> = TODO("provide the initial map here")

val myValues = inputMap.map { (l, c) -> ValueDescription(l, c) }
```

The `map` function here iterates over the entries of the map, and transforms each of them into a value of type `ValueDescription` by calling our lambda (the part between braces `{ ... }`).

Each entry of the map here contains a key (the length) and a value (the count). Instead of using `it.key` and `it.value`, you can also use parentheses like I did here with `(l, c)` to [destructure](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/destructuring-declarations.html) the entry into its 2 parts and give them names like `l` and `c`. The above is equivalent to:

```kotlin
val myValues = inputMap.map { ValueDescription(it.key, it.value) }
```